# Tomcat 8 new Resource implementation to map Jar files in a separate directory

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, tomcat8

With tomcat 8 I have extend the `WebAppClassLoader` and add some jar filed from a shared location to the classloader path using `addRepository()` method. With tomcat 8 `addRepository` have been removed and new resource implementation have been introduced. I'm still able to use the `addUrl` method to add jar files. But I would like to implement the new resource based implementation.

I've tried with

```
DirResourceSet dirResourceSet = new DirResourceSet(getContext().getResources(), "/WEB-INF/lib", "/home/thusitha/lib/runtimes/cxf", "/");
WebResourceRoot webResourceRoot = getContext().getResources();
webResourceRoot.getContext().getResources().addPreResources(dirResourceSet);
```

But this is not working and still it throws `classnotfoundexception`

Can someone tell me how to map a directory which contains jars to a particular webapp using Tomcat new resource implementation?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I spent the day trying to rework my app to use the resources system with no success. The technique I tried was to add the resources with a LifecycleListener on the Lifecycle.START_EVENT . As far as I can tell using a custom ClassLoader and/or addUrl is the only solution. This should probably be reported as a bug.

Comment: what I did was use addUrl method. I couldn't solve it using new resource implementation :(

Comment: It took me about 12 hours to find this solution, I don't believe it was worth the effort. My problem was the ContextConfig LifecycleListener was running BEFORE my custom LifecycleListener. When I moved my code into the ContextConfig everything just worked. Though this was specifically just testing for getting the JSTL library working. This may not solve every resource loading issue with the new system.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem is to register your resources by overriding the ContextConfig class (org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig). Catalina enters a starting state immediately after it scans your document path for resources. Most of the processing of those resources, such as annotations, is handled by the ContextConfig LifecycleListener. To ensure the resources are added before the context configuration takes place, override the ContextConfig.

```
    final Context currentContext = ctx;

    ContextConfig ctxCfg = new ContextConfig() {
        @Override
        public void lifecycleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) {
            if (event.getType().equals(Lifecycle.CONFIGURE_START_EVENT)) {

                WebResourceRoot webResourcesRoot = currentContext.getResources();

                String baseDir = Platform.getBaseDir(); // Server Base Directory

                File libDir = new File(baseDir + File.separator + "lib");

                DirResourceSet dirResourceSet = null;
                try {
                    dirResourceSet = new DirResourceSet(webResourcesRoot, "/WEB-INF/lib", libDir.getCanonicalPath(), "/");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

                webResourcesRoot.addPostResources(dirResourceSet);

                String[] possibleJars = dirResourceSet.list("/WEB-INF/lib");

                for(String libfile : possibleJars) {
                    WebResource possibleJar = dirResourceSet.getResource("/WEB-INF/lib/"+libfile);
                    System.err.println(String.format("Loading possible jar %s",possibleJar.getCanonicalPath())); // Just checking...
                    if (possibleJar.isFile() && possibleJar.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                        WebResourceSet resourceSet = new JarResourceSet(webResourcesRoot, "/WEB-INF/classes", possibleJar.getCanonicalPath(),"/");
                        webResourcesRoot.addPostResources(resourceSet);
                    }
                }
            }

            super.lifecycleEvent(event);
        }
    };

    ctx.addLifecycleListener(ctxCfg);
```

This is an undocumented solution that works on Tomcat 8.0.23. Considering the complexity and difficulty of this I can't say it is a better solution than adding jars directly to ClassLoaders.